# How to get Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01) wireless card working on Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian

I've tried many things, even updating the kernel to above 3.10. I've installed wireless tools and see the following from `lspci`:

```
sudo lspci | grep controller    
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)    
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

That's that output. When I do `iwconfig` I get the output:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.    
eth0      no wireless extensions.

make -C /lib/modules/3.16-0.bpo.3-amd64/build M=/home/dennis/Documents/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-0.bpo.3-amd64'
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-0.bpo.3-amd64'
  CC [M]  /home/dennis/Documents/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.o
In file included from /home/dennis/Documents/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:39:0:
/home/dennis/Documents/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/pci.h:247:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rtl_pci_probe’
/home/dennis/Documents/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c: In function ‘_rtl_init_mac80211’:
/home/dennis/Documents/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:365:4: error: ‘struct ieee80211_hw’ has no member named ‘channel_change_time’
/home/dennis/Documents/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c: In function ‘rtl_action_proc’:
/home/dennis/Documents/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:885:32: error: ‘struct ieee80211_conf’ has no member named ‘channel’
/home/dennis/Documents/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:886:32: error: ‘struct ieee80211_conf’ has no member named ‘channel’
/home/dennis/Documents/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c: In function ‘rtl_beacon_statistic’:
/home/dennis/Documents/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:1160:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘compare_ether_addr’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/dennis/Documents/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c: In function ‘rtl_send_smps_action’:
/home/dennis/Documents/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:1451:24: error: ‘struct ieee80211_conf’ has no member named ‘channel’
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[4]: *** [/home/dennis/Documents/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [_module_/home/dennis/Documents/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013] Error 2
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16-0.bpo.3-amd64'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

this is what happens when I try to do make install    root@debian:/home/dennis/Documents/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013#

Comment: Doesn't appear that your getting the wireless drivers loaded for your particular NIC.

Comment: What do i do? I have been siting here for hours, trying to get it to work...

Comment: Going up to 3.16 seems to resolve some of the issues as discussed in this thread: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=183886. That's with ArchLinux.

Comment: @slm how do i upgrade? Im new to linux

Comment: See here: http://www.tecmint.com/install-kernel-3-16-in-debian/

Comment: @slm Umm i tried it and it did not work...I must have messed up...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Older versions of Linux Kernel (< 3.x)

Found this thread which describes downloading the RTL8188EE Wireless NIC drivers, compiling them, and installing them.

- [Realtek RTL8188EE Laptop Wi-Fi Does not Work on Xbuntu 12.04](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2162026)

#### Excerpt of steps

1. Download drivers from [Realtek site](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=48&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#2722)
2. unzip, build, & install

   ```
   $ tar jxvf linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013.tar.bz2
   $ cd ~/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013
   $ make
   $ sudo make install
   ```
3. Load the kernel module (driver)

   ```
   $ sudo modprobe -v rtl8188ee
   ```

#### Newer versions of Linux Kernel (> 3.x)

This driver appears to already be included. I'm on Fedora 19 with a 3.14.x and can see that the module is already included.

```
$ locate rtl8188ee | grep -v "debug" | grep .ko
/usr/lib/modules/3.14.13-100.fc19.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8188ee/rtl8188ee.ko
/usr/lib/modules/3.14.15-100.fc19.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8188ee/rtl8188ee.ko
/usr/lib/modules/3.14.23-100.fc19.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8188ee/rtl8188ee.ko
```

So I would try manually loading the driver:

```
$ sudo modprobe -v rtl8188ee
```

There is also this bug regarding this driver with Ubuntu 14.04.

- [10ec:8179 (rev 01) RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter not working](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1314434)

  #### References
- [Ubuntu 12.04 Realtek RTL8188E Wireless Card Not Detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397983/ubuntu-12-04-realtek-rtl8188e-wireless-card-not-detected)

Comment: @AmateurProgramer - yeah I'm in and out of the site, please be patient. When I have time I'll read your replies.

Comment: @AmateurProgramer - can you run `locate rtl8188ee`, do you already have this driver? I'm on Fedora 19 w/ Kernel 3.14 and it appears to be including this driver now.